# Add custom button UISearchController in swift

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

i want to add a custom button on UISearchController in swift. [image]

Like this image i want to add the custom button. In this image it is a search bar. The plus button will show if there is text in the search bar and it will disappear if search bar is empty.  can any one help me to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

When the TextField changes, check for whitespace. 
Hide or position the button depending on whether it is blank or not. 
After the view is loaded, the text field is blank, so it is initialized with `ishidden()`.

I hope my answer is helpful to you.

**SearchViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class SearchViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var plusButton: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchTextField.delegate = self
        plusButton.isHidden = true
    }
    

    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if searchTextField.text == "" {
            plusButton.isHidden = true
        } else {
            plusButton.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

**Preview**

[image]